# Setting up WiFi on a RaspberryPi B with an Edimax EW-7811Un

Tags: raspbian, wifi, networking, wicd-curses

I have tried countless tutorials, but really none of them worked. No matter how I change my `interfaces` or `wpa_supplicant.conf` files - nothing worked. I even tried `wicd-curses` but somehow the program freezes whenever I try to connect to a network. So my `interfaces` now looks like this

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and `wpa_supplicant.conf` looks like this

```
network={
    ssid=“MYSSID“
    scan_ssid=1
    psk=“PASSWORD"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

I'm using `scan_ssid=1` because the network is hidden.

This configuration should actually work, but it does not. It only connects to the router with `eth0`.

So, is there a definitive and correct way to do this? There seem to be some many different ways to set up a WiFi connection, I really don't know how to do it.

Output of `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse b8:27:eb:6a:53:41  
          inet Adresse:192.168.2.122  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: 2003:86:2f5a:ba1d:26c5:2608:7646:8119/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          inet6-Adresse: 2003:86:2f5a:ba23:7bbf:3016:e479:fd5c/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          inet6-Adresse: 2003:86:2f5a:ba27:4a2f:bf56:a3cb:e076/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::ecd1:cbf5:2b05:2fb6/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX packets:45421 errors:0 dropped:450 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX bytes:3740778 (3.5 MiB)  TX bytes:1840132 (1.7 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX packets:520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
          RX bytes:42576 (41.5 KiB)  TX bytes:42576 (41.5 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 80:1f:02:e4:a6:fd  
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::1b55:1277:69f9:3979/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:12 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I really don't know where all the `inet6-addresses` are coming from.

Comment: Does it work if you stop trying to hide the SSID?

Comment: What distribution are you using? Why do you think it isn't working? What does `ifconfig` show?

Comment: It didn't work with other WiFi networks either. And I'm using the latest version of raspbian. I'll post the output of `ìfconfig` later on.